# How do I write a powershell script to install RDS-RD-Server role?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, powershell

I assumed I would just put the following in a filename.ps1 named file and run it like:

```
 powershell.exe -noexit 'filename.ps1'
```

It runs, but it's not doing anything.

Inside the filename.ps1 I have these two lines:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature RDS-RD-Server -restart
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

The execution policy is set to RemoteSigned *and* the individual commands do work inside PS without a script.

Comment: Is this for Server 2008 or Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Comment: I edited your tag to reflect this. 2008 R2 is very different than 2008. Be careful not to use them interchangeably.

Comment: In General with PS:  are you allowing unsigned scripts to run by changing the execution policy?  Do the individual commands work inside PS without a script?

Comment: The execution policy is set to RemoteSigned *and* the individual commands do work inside PS without a script.

Comment: You'll need PS to be running as Administrator as well.

Comment: I inadvertently discovered the problem:

The command I was using: powershell.exe -noexit 'filename.ps1'

It only requires single quotes if there's a space in the path to the file name. I removed the single quotes and for some reason this worked.  I don't quite understand why it worked though, because even if you have quotes around a path/filename in most circumstances it should work anyway.  I will post an answer to my own question tomorrow.

Comment: Is there a way to run the powershell.exe command in a batch file as admin?  It defeats the purpose of mass automation if I have to right click it and run as admin.

Answer (score 1):

> The command I was using: powershell.exe -noexit 'filename.ps1' It only requires single >quotes if there's a space in the path to the file name. I removed the single quotes and for >some reason this worked. I don't quite understand why it worked though...

By placing the quotes your output only returns the quoted text. If you command looked like this:

`powershell.exe -noexit & 'filename.ps1'`

it would execute the script because it has a Call operator (&)

> Is there a way to run the powershell.exe command in a batch file as admin? It defeats the >purpose of mass automation if I have to right click it and run as admin.

Running a batch file which runs a script seems counter intuitive... What capacity are you trying to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

@Sephethus - this answer is to a question in your comments, not the question posted (dont have enough rep to comment on this exchange yet)

> "Is there a way to run the powershell.exe command in a batch file as
>   admin? It defeats the purpose of mass automation if I have to right
>   click it and run as admin. – Sephethus yesterday"

Yes- if you invoke the command remotely on a list of servers it will run the command as an administrator because only local administrators have the permissions (by default) to invoke commands remotely with powershell.

Let me know if you want some sample code.